# How do I create animation with these data (snippet of xml file inside) and with scripting?

Tags: animation, scripting

I am new to scripting for blender, so yeah, I need help for creating an animation with data from .xml files.

(Below is the snippet of the .xml code)
[image: Below is the snippet of the .xml code]

I have already managed to create the rig that contains all the bones with the corresponding names that my animations need to track.

I'm also new to this forum, and I hope this is not an unreasonable and atrocious question to ask around here. Thanks.

edit: I apologized for the vague details on my post.

this is the work I've done so far, I've extracted data from a xml file to create the following rig with scripts.

[image]

Now, using the same xml file which also contains data for animations, I have to create the animation for the rig that I've done.

Comment: Please post what you created so far, so the current code. Did you check out the BVH import script? There's a lot of interesting code that deals with rotation angles and bones.

Comment: is the xml file a standard format? did it come from a recognised tool? There may well be existing import scripts if you know what you are looking for.